# One-Sample t Test and Likelihood Ratio Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

Concerning testing the hypotheses about the mean $\mu$ of a single population I know of things like the One-Sample $t$ test where there is a null hypothesis: $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$, and a test statistic $t = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}}$ is used to decide on rejecting or accepting the null hypothesis.

I encountered the notion of likelihood ratio test where a test is based on something like

$$\lambda(\textbf{x})=\frac{\sup_{\Theta_0}L(\theta|x)}{\sup_{\Theta}L(\theta|x)}$$

How does this likelihood ratio test compare or is related to the one-sample $t$ test. Obviously the $t$ test I mentioned is about means and the LRT says nothing about only dealing with means. So outside of dealing with means comparing the two makes no sense.

But does that mean when testing for means I should use the $t$ test and outside of dealing with means the LRT becomes relevant? So what would be the LRT in the same context of dealing with means that the $t$ test deals with?

Comment: The $t$-test for a mean $\mu$ is the likelihood ratio test! Check out [this link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/book/export/html/247) section "The T-Test For One Mean" or Example on page 71 of [this link](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~dlunn/b8_02/b8pdf_8.pdf). In a nutshell, you can get the critical value of the $t$-test using LRT.

Comment: @Stat: the links are dead. Do you know if there are still available out there? If not, would you be kind enough to write an answer to this question for the benefit of all?

Comment: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/book/export/html/847 is the unbroken first link.

It's a pretty straightforward exercise, take the ratio of the log-likelihoods w/ the MLE as needed and crank through the algebra. For normal distributions you can WLOG stick with standardized normal ones to make it simpler.